# Wy use the Rails envs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

Hello i'm starting to deploy my rails application in Digital Ocean host, before that i was developing locally and using webrick in Development mode, now that i'm deploy i'm using Unicorn in Production Env.
So if i change something on my sourcecode both envs will be affected. So why the exist? which the correct way to use it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails environments allow developers to maintain common elements (code, certain gems) and custom elements (other gems, environment settings, etc) for development, test and production.

For instance, you may want to use a simple DB like SQLite for development and just capture any emails generated in your log, but in production you want to use Postgres and (obviously) you need to send emails to users.  The Rails environment structure makes it very easy to maintain these separate configurations without duplication.

In your example, you want to use Unicorn in production as your application server.  This is easily accomplished by adding the Unicorn gem in a production group in your Gemfile like so:

```
group :production do
  gem 'unicorn',        '4.8.3'
end
```

Of course you will also need a Unicorn configuration file but hopefully this helps you appreciate the power and utility of Rails environments.

I would recommend taking some time to read the documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).